# ¿Cómo puedo restar el contenido de un arreglo en Java (BlueJ)?

Tags: java, array, poo, bucles, bluej

necesito ayuda con un problema que tengo con Java, más específicamente BlueJ.
Mi problema es que tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
private int [] metales;
   public Fabrica(){
        metales = new int[5];
   }
public String fabricar(){
        StringBuilder salida = new StringBuilder();
        salida.append("Reporte de fabricación: ");
        
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < metales.length; i++){
            total = total + metales[i];   
        }
        if (total >= materialNecesario){
            salida.append("Material fabricado correctamente");
            estados.add("OK");
        }
        else {
            salida.append("Creación fallida debido a falta de materiales"); 
            estados.add("Fallido");
        }
        return salida.toString();
    }
```

Al momento de usar el método fabricar(), cuando el "Material es fabricado correctamente", debería restar 10 (que es el valor de la variable `materialNecesario`) de cualquiera de las celdas del array, de la totalidad de ellos, o de la suma de varios. No sé si se puede hacer lo que estoy preguntando. Me sería de gran ayuda si alguien me logra explicar cómo se hace para aplicarlo en un futuro en mis estudios :c

Comment: ¡Hola Mabela! ¡Bienvenida! Un gusto leer tus intenciones de aprender pero vas a ser  un poco más específica. ¿Cuál de las tres cosas quieres hacer? ¿Restar una cantidad a cada elemento de un array? ¿Restar una cantidad a un solo elemento? ¿Restar una cantidad a varios elementos? Son tres cosas bastante diferentes. Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/539796/edit) agregando detalles y ejemplos y especificando entradas y salidas. Por ejemplo: Si tengo [5, 4, 2, 4, 1], y le resto a cada elemento 1 quiero obtener [4,3,1,3,0]. (un ejemplo así podrías poner)

Comment: Tal vez fui yo quien no te entendió bien, así que unos ejemplos no estarían de más. De cualquier forma, me imaginé algo como [esto](https://onlinegdb.com/0PytunaA4I), pero tu eres quien tiene la última palabra. Por último, y solo como dato, java es el mismo en todos lados. No importa si es Bluej, IntelliJ, Visual Studio Code, Eclipse o Netbeans, en todos se haría igual. El programa es solo una herramienta, pero el lenguaje es el mismo.